# Radiation Emission due to High Temperatures?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, astrophysics, atomic-physics, photon-emission, ground-state

We know that an object emits radiation at all temperatures above absolute zero.

But when an object is heated to high temperatures like the **stars**, Wouldn't it cause **thermionic emission** to take place?

Due to which, the excited electrons wouldn't be able to release emission and come to the ground State *(there wouldn't be any thermal equilibrium),* because they are not bound to the atom anymore?

Answer (score 1):

Thermionic emission is a term that only applies to solids. In solids, interactions between atoms are strong enough to distort electron energy levels into energy *bands*. Thermionic emission is specifically when an solid object is hot enough that the electrons have enough energy to jump out of the highest-energy band (the conduction band) and escape the solid.

Gaseous objects don't have these kinds of interactions, and don't have energy bands, so thermionic emission isn't really a concept that makes sense there. And at temperatures around that of the surface of stars, you're not really going to have solids anymore - everything is going to be either a gas or a plasma.

That said, for gases, you can have *thermal ionization* occur, where the atoms are moving around fast enough that collisions between them can dislodge electrons, forming a mix of electrons, ions, and neutral gas atoms. This isn't thermionic emission, but it roughly approximates what the rest of your question is about.

Electrons definitely *can* still emit radiation when they're not part of an atom. In fact, that's the entire reason a free-electron laser works (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-electron_laser). Electrons emit radiation every time they accelerate, which, in a chaotic medium like a plasma with substantial microscopic electric fields, is quite often.

Thermal equilibrium *can* still exist in a plasma, as long as the amount of heat input is equal to the amount of heat lost to radiation. At any moment in time, the number of electrons that emit enough energy to be recombined into neutral atoms is equal to the number of electrons that are dislodged by collisions, so the populations of electrons, ions, and neutral atoms remain the same. And the temperature of each of the species also remains constant; the amount of energy transferred from electrons to ions via collisions is the same as the amount of energy transferred from ions to electrons.

Thermal equilibrium **almost never** means that everything is in the ground state. The *only* situation in which thermal equilibrium is the same as the ground state is at absolute zero. For any nonzero temperature, thermal equilibrium means that at least some portion of the population is in an excited state at any moment in time.